# Is there an equivalent to the Windows Phone for my Windows PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, email, contacts, social-networking

I have Windows Phone 7(.5) which collects all my emails (in one feed, and synchronising it online), collects calendar items from multiple locations (including facebook) and all my contacts (from email accounts, facebook, twitter and linkedin) with linking.

I have used outlook recently, but it seems not to be able to do even half of that. Is there any lovely software (preferably pretty) that does what my Phone does, except on my PC (which is running Windows 7).

I'm tempted just to use the Windows Phone 7 Emulator and mirror it to how my phone is set up, but that's not really what I'm looking for.

Any help would be fantastic.

Cheers

**Features**

- Synchronise all Emails from multiple servers (Live, Gmail, maybe Facebook & Twitter too)
- Display Emails in single window, preferably grouped together
- Get all Contacts (with all specified contact information, plus profile pictures) from specified accounts (Live, Gmail, Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn)
- Links Contacts together (Live, Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn)
- Pulls Calendar items from multiple locations (Live, Gmail, Facebook, Feeds)

Essentially, the features that Microsoft boast about for their phone, but haven't made for windows

Comment: Can you list all of the features that you need (what info to pull & where to display it)? I've got a few apps in mind but they are slightly different, so details are needed.

Comment: @dnbrv righto, they're up. What apps were you thinking of?

Comment: You would think Outlook, but Outlook's UI is long in the tooth.

Comment: @surfasb i've tried lots of things in outlook, but its such a pain, and still misses lots of the functionality. sadly another missed step from microsoft

Answer (score 2):

*Note to moderators and trigger-happy community members:* This answer is full of links and brief instructions because of the sheer volume of requested information. I've spent a considerable time searching & consolidating it. If I were to include all of the instructions in plain text, it would've been an enormously long & less coherent response.

---

First off, Windows Phone (and any other mobile OS) does all of the features you mentioned through a number of plugins and the whole environment has been designed for that use. Thus, it's not easy to replicate the behavior on desktops. Most (not everything) of what you want can be done in Outlook with a few plugins.

**Email consolidation** requires [Google IMAP](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77695) and [Outlook Hotmail Connector](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/microsoft-office-outlook-hotmail-connector-overview-HA010222518.aspx) (it will take care of Live email, calendar, and contacts). Facebook Inbox can't be synced with any email client. There's one [Twitter plugin for Outlook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/twinbox-EM010292097.aspx?CTT=1) and a few [desktop clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Twitter_services_and_applications) (pick whatever you like).

Outlook 2010 is the only version of Outlook so far that allows conversation threading.

**Contacts**

You *can't sync contacts* from Google, Facebook, Twitter, or LinkedIn with Outlook. However, you *can import some* of them manually: [GMail](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=24911), [LinkedIn](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3/ls/1040%2C1043%2C1236%2C1870), Facebook contacts can be exported [only via Yahoo](http://www.labnol.org/internet/export-email-addresses-from-facebook/12970/) (everything else is shady or dead). Once you have all of the exported contacts, you'll need to [import them into Outlook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/import-contacts-HA101870645.aspx) and manage duplicates. After that you'll need to install either [Xobni](http://www.xobni.com) or [Gist](http://www.gist.com), which will pull photos and recent updates from all the connected services.

**Calendars**

Google Calendar can be synced with Outlook with the [dedicated utility](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=98563).

Outlook (or any other calendar) can only subscribe to Facebook calendars. Here's how to do it [in Outlook 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/view-and-subscribe-to-internet-calendars-HA102534443.aspx?CTT=1) and here's how to do it in [Outlook 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/view-and-subscribe-to-internet-calendars-HA010167325.aspx?CTT=1).

You can get Facebook events calendar feed by going to [Facebook Events](http://www.facebook.com/events/), clicking export at the bottom of the page, and copying the link in the dialogue. You can get Facebook birthday calendar feed by going to [Facebook birthdays](https://www.facebook.com/events/birthdays/), clicking export at the bottom of the page, and copying the link in the dialogue.

---

If anything is missing, ask away in the comments, I'll clarify there or edit the answer.

Comment: thank you for this answer. I am already using IMAP and Live Connector to get my emails together, but the main issue that is causing most of my issues is the contats syncing. But I'll have a look at those two you have suggested. Same goes for the Calendar

Comment: Have you tried the rest of the setup?

Comment: yes, I have tried the calendar setup, but I need to keep downloading the calendars from facebook to keep everything updated. The contacts for facebook works, but its irritating to keep updating them when I add new friends, or they update their contact information.